# Boost Items in Game Dev Story

Tags: game-dev-story

I've been playing Game Dev Story a bit lately, and have gotten to the point where I own all the boost items, have a fair bit of tech, and are consistently selling really well with my games - though I haven't yet gotten a GOTY award.

My theory is that if I want that award, I need to pump up the stats of the game during development (makes sense). It stands to reason that the Boost Items help with this.

However, I am a little confused as to who I should select to use the Boost items, when to use them, and how often I should. Can anyone help me here? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boost items act fairly similarly to when one of your employees asks you if they can attempt to improve the current game. You spend the research points that it tells you (you can't increase the amount of points you spend) and the game allows you to select which employee should use the boost. However, the main difference is that the boost doesn't fail. I'd if you have a project that's looking good, use the boost items as many times as your research points allow to patch of the weak points.

One thing to note - the items don't disappear after you use them.

Comment: Wait, the boost items can *fail*? I've seen them have nearly no effect at all (1-2 points), but I've never seen outright failure like when an employee takes the initiative.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "whereas there's a chance of your employee failing the task if he or she approaches you", I meant when your employee takes the initiative. I guess that was a little confusing so I took that part out.

Comment: Ah, yeah - now that I re-read the old post, I can see I did indeed misread it. My mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

Certain classes are better at certain boosts. If you do a little trial and error, this will leap out at you. Generally you get about 15 points per boost, but if you boost with the "best" class, it'll go into the 20's.

Edit:
Producers are the best to boost "Creativity"
Directors are the best to boost "Fun"
Hackers do well at Graphics and Sound, but Designers and Sound Eng do better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Game of the Year you need to boost all four elements well over 100 each - I only got to GOTY with all four elements above 150.  This was with a PC game (didn't need to be on a console).

To achieve GOTY you need plenty of money, research data, dead bulls and for the boosts to be already paid for.

Then you pay for the most expensive external people to do the design/graphics/sound; use dead bull to keep the team energy high and have plenty of research data handy for several 30 point chunks needed for each boost.

Taking dead bull just before a boost or two seems to improve the value of the boost as well as generating plenty of extra research data.

Throw in a bit of advertising for the fame/hype burst and you'll be there.

Answer (score 0):

Boost items are pretty useless as they only raise by 10-20 on average. But if your counting on gathering a bunch of research points to boost often it won't work because the more research points you have ,  the more each boost consumes them. To achieve GOTY I had about 300 in fun and another stat in the 200 range and the others between 100 and 200. After training your staff a bit and combining combinations deemed as amazing you will eventually get it. In my game which ran for 40 years i only won it 5 times. Once you win GOTY make a sequel the next year almost worked out perfectly for me although I missed the award with some sequels while later sequels won it.